# Am I playing easy or normal?

Tags: ftl-faster-than-light

During a game, how can I tell if the difficulty is easy or normal? I can't remember my choice.

Comment: If you are new to the game, and can make it past sector 2, you are probably playing on easy. That said, even easy can be pretty darn hard the first time. The best way to know is to remember what you select on the new game selection screen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to check your difficulty in-game, while you are in the middle of a round.

However, if you never touched the difficulty option, the default is Normal (Which is pretty difficult).

If you REALLY wanted to know, you could always open up the save file in a hex editing program, as all game info is stored there.

Comment: What would one look for to determine difficulty using a hex editor?